# How can I get a list of all functions in a project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to programmatically pull a list of all of the functions in a project in Google Apps. There doesn't seem to be a method in any of the services that easily pulls them except it seems to be stored in the .this function in one way or another. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a list of function.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Apps Script API is used for retrieving the list of functions. When the method of projects.getContent of Apps Script API is used, you can retrieve all function names in the project of Google Apps Script.

#### Try this API:

At first, as a test case, you can test it at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent?apix_params=%7B%22scriptId%22%3A%22Please%20set%20your%20script%20ID%20here%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(functionSet%2Cname)%22%7D). When you use this, please set the script ID and `files(functionSet,name)` to `fields`.

#### Sample script:

This is a sample script of Google Apps Script. The method of projects.getContent of Apps Script API is used. Before you use this script, please do the following settings.

Settings:

1. Add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects.readonly` to the scopes.
2. [If the script for running this script is created after April 8, 2019, please link the Cloud Platform Project to the Google Apps Script Project.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)
3. Enable Apps Script API at API console.
4. Copy and paste the following sample script.
5. Run `myFunction()`.

By this, the list of all functions can be retrieved.

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var scriptId = "###"; // Please set the script ID here.

  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content?fields=files(functionSet%2Cname)";
  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `this` is used. This is also mentioned by your question. In this case, no API is used. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and run `myFunction()`. By this, the list of all functions can be retrieved.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var key in this) {
    if (typeof this[key] == "function") {
      Logger.log(key)
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

- Also both patterns can retrieved the script of each function.

#### References:

- [Method: projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent?apix_params=%7B%22scriptId%22%3A%22Please%20set%20your%20script%20ID%20here%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files%2FfunctionSet%22%7D)
- [Google Cloud Platform Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: THANK YOU! You understood my question correctly and pattern 2 was exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to avoid using the API. I tested your script from pattern 2 and it logged the functions exactly.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: where can I learn more about this `fields=files(functionSet%2Cname)`

Comment: @Cooper From `can I learn`, in my case, I use [Google API Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery). The values retrieved by this API includes all values for Google APIs. From this, I check the field values. Google API Discovery Service has 2 methods of list and getRest. When the api name and version have already been known, the values can be directly retrieved by the method of getRest. This method was simpler for me. Or I think that the field value can be also checked from "Response body" of each method. If these were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Pattern 2 works very well but it will not include the functions in any script inside HTML

Answer (score 0):

Greate pattern 2 sample script!
And it can be even simple:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var key in this) {
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

Because of `typeof this[key]` will always == "function", just remove `if()` and got same result