# How to find repeated variables or functions with the same name within other files in the new apps script IDE

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

The are many things I like about the new Apps Script IDE. But in the old IDE I used to be able to invoke the find dialog box to search for a function or variable name and the dialog box would return a list of files it was found in.

In the new IDE I can only search the active file on the window.

For example; In this case I referred to a function my JS file and the dialog box listed the files containing that function or variable name. This greatly reduces the time spent looking for the function when you have hundreds if not thousands of functions and files.

[image]

Is there a way to search all files in the new IDE?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Right** click on the variable/function name you want to search for references:

   [image]

---

2a. **Left** click on **Peek Definition** (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) if you want to see **all the function declarations** of the selected name:

[image]

---

2b. **Left** click on **Peek References** if you want to see **all the declarations** (functions and variables) of the selected name:

[image]

---

**Please note:**

- The pop up window directs you to the reference scripts so you can edit them inside that window.
- Click on the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button if you want to escape the pop up window.

---

### References:

In this article you can find a rich documentation of the most functionalities of the new `ide`:

- [A Guide To The New Google Apps Script IDE](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/)

Comment: Thank you for that Marios. This works if the references(function or variable) are in the same file. What I'm looking to find is where else(in the `entire` project not just in that file) I referenced the function or variable.

Comment: @user2916405 **No**. Please see both screenshots again. This is looking for the references in **every** script in your file. See the screenshots ; on the right side of the image you can see and select the script that this function/variable appears.

Comment: I see. What if I need to search from an html file say I have referenced the function  getPriceAndQty in my JS front end code  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadupdate)
                 .getPriceAndQty(fieldData);` How would I start the search from the front end  file?

Comment: @user2916405 not sure about that. It is a very specific functionality which I doubt exists. I would advice you to post a new question regarding that follow-up and consider accepting this answer to help future readers navigate easier to the solution. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: @NaziA thanks for the proposed edits. Unfortunately, my review privileges are suspended so I can't accept your helpful edits. Hopefully, other people can do that instead of me.

Comment: You can cmd+click on the function name as well!

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1. Get all function names

[Use API method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent?apix_params=%7B%22scriptId%22%3A%22Please%20set%20your%20script%20ID%20here%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(functionSet%2Cname)%22%7D) to get the list of functions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57105972/5372400

### Step 2. Get Duplicates

Copy the text of the API Results to Google Sheets, and use this formula to find duplicates:

`=QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A,"name\: .*")), "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1"),"where Col2 > 1")`