# best practices to navigate google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

loving the new interface but it's super hard to navigate around the script. The collapse/expand are essentially useless for me. I hope this isn't just closed. It seems like a valid question especially with a new published coding interface.

What methods do people use

(1) to jump to a function in a script file

(2) to jump to functions in other script files

(bonus) to catalog what user functions are used in a function?

Comment: You could use fold all to more easily find all the functions on a page

Comment: I don't think that you can jump to a function in another script.  I hope I find that I'm wrong.

Comment: @Cooper Well, its possible. Jason have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65564379/11225291.

Comment: @Cooper project no, but different scripts within the same project yes..

Comment: @Cooper not sure about the official documenation but in my mind all scripts that are in the same script editor belong to the same project :P not sure if that makes sense. But all them live under the same `url`.

Comment: @Cooper no problem, we educate each other, that's what we do here :)

Comment: @Cooper c'mon man. functions are within functions, right? doesn't that make sense to you? don't you put functions in your functions? I moderate coding forums and I try not to ridicule people without pretty good reason.

So like if I build sendemail() and that calls prepemail() and buildtext() I'd want some way to know those two function calls are in the main function without just eyeballing all the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try navigating to a definition, reference or symbol by using the `Go to Definition`, `Go to Reference` or `Go to Symbol`  commands.

You can execute those commands by using the short-cuts `Ctrl+F12`, `Shift+F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+O` respectively, or by right-clicking text in your code to bring up the context menu. Doesn't seem to work with closures though.

The new editor has a bunch of new options and features. Easiest way to find and explore them is by opening the command palette by pressing `F1`.

Comment: thanks. hoping there was more of a quick jump menu like VBA offers... I can work with that though.

Comment: **UPDATE** In some cases, if you hold down **`ctrl`** and hover over a function declaration, a hyperlink is generated. Clicking the link **should** take you to the function definition. Doesn't always work though. I suspect that one's code structure has to conform to some standard for it all to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
Press `cmd` and click on the function name. It opens a pop-up with the original function.

PS: Does somebody know how to open up the pop-up and go to that file?

**Solution 2**
Install [AppsScript Color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appsscript-color/ciggahcpieccaejjdpkllokejakhkome?hl=en) and do a search and click the magnifying glass to search through all files.

[image]
[image]